# how to use pipe (concatnate cmd)

Tags: shell-script

i am having trouble to execute "|" command in root mode, the command is as follows

```
cat xyz.sh | chmod 744 xyz.sh | echo "hello" > xyz.sh
```

and when i run this command using **./xyz.sh**, an error occurs

```
./xyz.sh: line 1: hello: command not found
```

please specify me. If, i am doing something wrong with reason!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that one-liner? Maybe I'm missing something but in its current state it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: That command doesn't make any sense whatsoever. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just wanted to know, why *command not found* error is coming even the output is generated!

Comment: But it doesn't make sense. Tell us what you're trying to do and you'll get some help that may also explain the "command not found".

Comment: I want to make *xyz.sh file*, pass some argument in it, without getting into xyz.sh file.

Comment: `echo "hello" > xyz.sh` does not "pass some argument in it", it overwrites the file's contents with the word `hello`. It should be obvious why `./xyz.sh` then produces the error `line 1: hello: command not found`

Comment: Perhaps this is a language issue. What do you mean by "_without getting into `xyz.sh` file_"? (Do you mean "without overwriting it"?)

Comment: Actually, i am creating *xyz.sh file* for the first time. So, it’s obvious that there is nothing inside the file and at this time i want to insert any kinda comment or any argument under the file without getting into it. So, I believe that there no question of overwriting the file. Because, getting into the file, pass some parameters then saving it and getting out of the file takes lots of time.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to understand [what a pipeline is](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02):

> A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by the control operator `|`. For each command but the last, the shell shall connect the standard output of the command to the standard input of the next command

What happens in your pipeline is the following:

1. `cat` sends the content of `xyz.sh` to the standard input of the next command.
2. `chmod` receives that data but, AFAIK, it doesn't do anything with it. Instead, it changes the permissions of `xyz.sh` and sends nothing to the standard input of the next command.
3. `echo` receives nothing but it doesn't matter because `echo` doesn't read standard input in the first place. As [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) said, `echo` overwrites the content of `xyz.sh` with the word `hello`.

Then, if you try to run `xyz.sh`, the only statement your shell finds is `hello` and it will try to run `hello` as a command. You don't have any `hello` command installed, so that's why you get the `command not found` error.